# ECLIPSE E4 - Save Workspace status

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

Hey guys I'd like to deal with persisted data in order to save my Application Status before quitting. Well in order to give it a try I created a dirtyable object in an MPART then added a saving handler linked to a menu entry.

Here it's:
MPART:

```
txtInput.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
                @Override
                public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
                    dirty.setDirty(true);
                }
            });
```

Handler:

```
@Execute
public void execute(EPartService partService) {
    partService.saveAll(false);
}
```

At the end I also removed the -clearpersistedstate argument from the running configuration but every time I launch my app, it doesn't save changes inside the MPART but only changes at perspective level E.g: If an MPART has been closed in the following execution it will be kept closed.

Any hints?

Comment: Have you added an @Persist method to your part?

Comment: Yes I did @Persist
 public void save() {
  dirty.setDirty(false);
 }

Comment: But that is not persisting the state anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EPartService.saveAll` just calls any method annotated with `@Persist` in the parts. This will be done automatically when the workspace is shutdown anyway.

Note: The part must be marked as dirty for the @Persist method to be called.

So to save any details in your part you need a method:

```
@Persist
void save()
{
  ... save your data somewhere
}
```

when your part is created again you have to load your data from your saved data.

One place to save data is the `MPart` persisted state - access this with:

```
Map<String, String> persistedState = part.getPersistedState();
```

You can save string values in this map.

So:

```
@Persist
void save(MPart part)
{
   Map<String, String> persistedState = part.getPersistedState();

   persistedState.put("key for my value", "my value");
}
```

and retrieve it with:

```
@PostConstruct
void createPart(MPart part)
{
   Map<String, String> persistedState = part.getPersistedState();

   String myValue = persistedState.get("key for my value");
}
```

Comment: Please could you give me an example of what I should put in the "save your data somewhere" part? What are the objects that I can use there?

Comment: That depends on what you want to save. In an editor for example you would save the file here. If  you just want to save a string use the persisted state.

Comment: Is there any method to set the MPart Persisted State? For instance with a String...

Answer (score 0):

Greg,
well I have understood how to use the Map type but I didn't catch how my Map variable becomes "persistent".  My implementation as follows:

```
persistedState = part.getPersistedState();
        System.out.println(persistedState.get("1"));
```

...

```
@Persist
    public void save() {
        dirty.setDirty(false);
persistedState.put("1", "test1");
}
```

Obviously doesn't work when I exit the app, I stil miss the last piece of the puzzle.
Has it something to do with Preference Store/ writing a file with my stuff in it?

Comment: Don't use answers to ask questions - edit your question. Don't save the persisted state map - get it from the part each time you need it. Make sure your part is marked dirty and that the @Persist method is being called.

Comment: Sorry greg I'll keep that in mind next time. Anyway does it work even though I quit the app and start it again? Will the persisted data be kept in place?

Comment: Yes persisted state is kept until you do a start with the -clearPersistedState flag

Comment: greg unfortunately it doesn't work when quitting. If I close the MPart while keeping the app running, I'm able to retrieve the persistedState's key, otherwise I only get an empty string :( I underline that the -clearPersistedState flag is not present in the args list. Like there's a getPersistedState() for MPart is there any method to set it?

Comment: Works for me, and is used extensively inside Eclipse.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it works for you but I'd like to pinpoint it in order to understand where I'm wrong... It seems that Eclipse is erasing data as soon as I restart the application.

Comment: Greg, I have figured out what was happening... I was using the getPersistedState() method on an MPart rather than on MApplication...